# What is the difference between these two function prologue instruction sequences?

Tags: assembly, x86, c, gcc

the test is on `32-bit x86`. I compiled the code with `gcc 4.2`, optimization level `o2`. I compiled the C code into binary, and then use `objdump` to disassemble it.

Here are two sequences of instructions used for the function prologue:

```
0804a6f0 <quotearg_n>:
804a6f0:       8b 44 24 04             mov    0x4(%esp),%eax
804a6f4:       b9 ff ff ff ff          mov    $0xffffffff,%ecx
804a6f9:       8b 54 24 08             mov    0x8(%esp),%edx
804a6fd:       c7 44 24 04 40 e1 04    movl   $0x804e140,0x4(%esp)
804a704:       08 
804a705:       e9 c6 fa ff ff          jmp    804a1d0 <quotearg_n_options>
804a70a:       8d b6 00 00 00 00       lea    0x0(%esi),%esi


0804a730 <quotearg>:
804a730:       83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
804a733:       8b 44 24 20             mov    0x20(%esp),%eax
804a737:       c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
804a73e:       89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
804a742:       e8 a9 ff ff ff          call   804a6f0 <quotearg_n>
804a747:       83 c4 1c                add    $0x1c,%esp
804a74a:       c3                      ret
804a74b:       90                      nop
804a74c:       8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
```

Note that in function `quotearg`, register `esp` is decreased with `0x1c` before it is used to access the stack and get some arguments. Accutually according to my experience, I think the `sub` then `access` pattern is quite common for instructions compiled with `O2`.

However, note that in function `quotearg_n`, register `esp` is directly added with `0x4` to access the stack. (I think the meaning of instruction at address `0x804a6f0` is to put the return address of call site to register `eax`, am I right..?) According to my observation, the pattern used by the first function is rare, around 5% for `gcc` compiled middle size C program with `O2`.

So here is my question:

Why does compiler generate function prologue instructions in a way similar to `quoterag_n`? What is the exact meaning of the first three instructions start from address `0x804a6f0`?

Why doesn't compiler always generate function prologue instructions following the `sub` then `access` pattern? (such as `quoterag`)

Am I clear? thanks a lot

Comment: Is there a reason for you to use an 8-year-old compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the functions are defined like this:

```
int quotearg_n(int a, int b) {
    return quotearg_n_options(a, b, -1, "some_string");
}

int quotearg(int a) {
    return quotearg_n(0, a);
}
```

(the `int`s might as well be pointers, can't tell this from your snippets, and the "some string" might be a pointer to a pre-initialized structure)

These functions have the normal `ABI`, which means they pass all arguments on the stack, while `quotearg_n_options` receives the first three of its arguments in registers, and only the last one on the stack. This might be due to a modifier in the function's prototype, and it might also be due to the function being declared `static`, so the compiler knows it can't be called from outside the current source file so it's safe to change it's `ABI`.

Now, from `quotearg` to `quotearg_n`, the number of parameters on the stack increases, so the compiler **needs to make room for them**, initializes them, calls the subroutine, and returns.

From `quotearg_n` to `quotearg_n_options`, the number of parameters increases again (from 2 to 4), but since three parameters are passed in registers `eax`, `edx` and `ecx`, only the string has to be on the stack. Which means the number of parameter on the stack *decreases*, so **the call needs *less* stack space**, which allows the compiler to recycle the current stack. So what the compiler does is something called *tail call elimination*: instead of calling the function, then returning, it sets up the stack in the way the callee expects it, then jumps to it instead of using a call. That function (`quotearg_n_options`) will execute, and when it returns, it will directly return to the function that called `quotearg_n`, the original one.

So to answer your question: The compiler uses the [tail call elimination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization) optimization, which it can do only if the number of parameters *on the stack* of the called function is lower than the number of parameters *on the stack* of the caller.